# C# await Task.Delay(1000); only takes 640ms to return

Tags: c#, wpf

So, this is simple to explain, but I have searched and cannot find anyone with the same issue. My problem originated in a long-term periodic task which was running more frequently than I wanted. It seems every Task.Delay() I create and await returns in about 65% of the delay I specified in ms.

The problem boiled down to the following line of code returning in roughly 640-660ms (According to visual studio. I set a breakpoint on this line of code and the one following it, and it said that's how long had passed):

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

On two other machines, the IDENTICAL code base runs just fine. Not only this simple statement above, but the periodic tasks as well. Is there a setting somewhere that would affect Task.Delay(int millisecondsDelay)? Tick type, clock speed, anything, system clock??? I am at a loss...

EDIT:

In the snippet below, EtMilliseconds is anywhere from 130-140ms, which is the same approx. 65% of expected duration seen above. Never anything outside that (besides the first time into the while() which is irrelevant).

```
Long EtMilliseconds;
Stopwatch etWatch = new Stopwatch();
etWatch.Restart();

while (true)
{
  EtMilliseconds = etWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  taskDelay = Task.Delay(200);
  etWatch.Restart();
  await taskDelay;
}
```

EDIT 2:

The following code causes EtMilliseconds to be once again 131ms or so. Using Thread.Sleep seems to have no effect...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        long EtMilliseconds;
        Stopwatch etWatch = new Stopwatch();
        etWatch.Restart();

        while (true)
        {
            EtMilliseconds = etWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            label.Content = EtMilliseconds.ToString();
            etWatch.Restart();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet is the same but uses Task.Delay(200). This one updates the GUI label correctly (the Thread.Sleep does not) and it is either 131 or 140ms. Always...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task taskDelay;
        long EtMilliseconds;
        Stopwatch etWatch = new Stopwatch();
        etWatch.Restart();

        while (true)
        {
            EtMilliseconds = etWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            label.Content = EtMilliseconds.ToString();
            taskDelay = Task.Delay(200);
            etWatch.Restart();
            await taskDelay;
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT 3:

Using DispatcherTimer instead, I still get approx 130ms from my Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds... BUT here's the strange thing. If I also update a display of DateTime.Now(), they increment by just about 200ms (or slightly more), which is what I would expect. What the?!?!
[image]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public long etMilliseconds;
    public Stopwatch etWatch;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    //  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.Tick handler
    //
    //  Updates the current seconds display and calls
    //  InvalidateRequerySuggested on the CommandManager to force 
    //  the Command to raise the CanExecuteChanged event.
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Updating the Label which displays the current second
        tBoxCurrTime.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MMM_dd-hh:mm:ss.fff_tt") + "\n";
        tBoxMilliSecElapsed.Text += etWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\n";
        etWatch.Restart();

        // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        etWatch = new Stopwatch();

        //  DispatcherTimer setup
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

        etWatch.Restart();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know there are some global flags in windows that affect timer resolution but I for the life of me can't remember what they are called or what native calls you have to make to check or set them. [Found it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx), maybe the machine that works correctly has that flag set.

Comment: This is an async call, it isn't supposed to last 1000 ms. Rather, it will continue execution from the very next line when 1000 ms passes. Are you sure you measure the time correctly there then? Could you edit your question to show how the measurement is performed?

Comment: What are you using to measure the time between the begin and end of `Task.Delay`? If you want to be accurate you should be using a `Stopwatch` instance. Also make sure that the `.Delay` is actually being awaited and that your call stack to that point uses the `async/await` pattern all the way down. Also make sure that the scope of your `StopWatch` is set correctly, you do not want a shared instance that another thread could make changes to.

Comment: @Igor I think he is using the tools built in to the debugger that shows you how long it took to do a "step over" operation. But I agree, try measuring with StopWatch.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain See edit. No matter the value, the delay is always 65% of what's expected.

Comment: @GaryWillette did you try if it happens with `Thread.Sleep` aswell? just to try. I can definitely not reproduce on my machine :-/

Comment: The accuracy of the timer should be about 15ms, you could try the sample code here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2 to check how it behaves on your machine.

Comment: Yep, can't reproduce. Just ran your second example, and all intervals in the 200-213 range here.

Comment: Just brain storming here but what is your calling harness? Maybe its related to that? Unit test, Console app, WPF, Web Api, etc??

Comment: I tried both WPF and Winforms and they are consistently 200-211ms with the second example. **Edit**: console worked fine aswell

Comment: Is your system clock running on time? I once had an issue with NTP that made my clock run super fast...

Comment: Can't repro either. Is this really all of your code? If you're doing something expensive while you're doing your timing (like writing to a log file or something) then you'd soak up some of the time you're trying to measure.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I tested playing with `timeBeginPeriod` and `timeEndPeriod` and didn't make a difference :-/

Comment: @spender Yes my PC time is accurate. It gets updated from a time server, but I don't know if that happens often enough to mask out any discrepancies there may be...

Comment: Do you have access to a different PC? Port a compiled version of your WPF test app that writes output to a label or textbox over to another computer and validate the results on that PC. This should be able to confirm or refute if its an issue with your PC's system clock or the complete/compiled code.

Comment: @Igor in my initial question I mentioned that the full code base (not only the simple 'await Task.Delay(1000)' work just great on not one but two other machines... Also, please see my last edit where I use Thread.Sleep() and Task.Delay() with identical results.

Comment: I tested both your edits and both always produce a value in the `EtMilliseconds` variable of `200` or more. I would look in your windows event log to see if there is anything suspicious in there, look for Errors, warnings, critical event types in the System and Application folders. If that does not turn up anything start Googling something like [your o/s] + system timer problems.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you use a DispatcherTimer instead of `Task.Delay`?

Comment: @devuxer please see my latest update. On a 200ms delay/interval, the stopwatch is showing an ET of about 130ms, while DateTime.Now() is incrementing by about 200ms. What gives?!

Comment: @GaryWillette - have you looked at your windows event log yet to see if there is anything suspicious? Recurring warnings, errors, criticals, etc in the System folder or Application folder?

Comment: @Igor where would I locate the System folder or Application folder? Yes I looked at the System logs, no errors or warnings all afternoon...

Comment: @GaryWillette - i wrote a quick javascript harnes to test out. This would eliminate c# as the culprit and point the finger at your system or o/s if you can reproduce it there.

Comment: I tested and I got 1000ms as desired... Is it possible that my Stopwatch.Frequency is incorrect??? This is a read-only property, so I'm not sure how it would be wrong or how to change it...

Comment: What happens if you extend the time to like 10 seconds, and use the stopwatch on your phone (or some other external stopwatch) to see if you are systematically off with that as well. Obviously, your reaction time will add a small amount of error, but if you make the time long enough, you shouldn't be off by the large percentages you're seeing now.

Comment: On which CPU are You running this? Stopwatch uses Rtdsc which according to the Intel Manuals count the number of executed cycles on one core. This was changed for Intel CPUs later than ca. 2008. Check out with Sysinterals Tool coreinfo if your CPU supports constant rtdsc. It might help to set in the Windows settings the power plan to high performance to get rid of CPU frequency changes. For more infos see http://www.luxford.com/high-performance-windows-timers

Comment: @devuxer My GUI (in this test app) updates exactly once every 10sec. The DateTime.Now() is accurate, but the stopwatch is showing 6595ms or thereabouts.

Comment: @AloisKraus I have it set to High performance already, plugged in, which sets min and max processor state to 100% according to the power plan. It is a Intel Core i5, 2.6GHz quad core

Comment: Okay, so the delay is actually the amount of time you requested, but the thing you are using to measure the delay (`Stopwatch` or VisualStudio debugger) is reporting a shorter duration?

Comment: @devuxer yes that seems to be correct. Both the Stopwatch and the VisualStudio debugger agree and are incorrect. The DateTime.Now() and REAL time is accurate. This was confirmed using the 10sec delay as you suggested.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534957/c-sharp-stopwatch-shows-incorrect-time?

Comment: @devuxer This is very intriguing. I ran Prime95 (recommended by usr below) and had my CPU pegged at 100%. Then I ran my program and yielded the same results :-(

Comment: Damn, I have no idea at this point. I assume you are using the latest .NET Framework build?

Comment: @devuxer I believe so, 4.6.2? So I've decided that even if disabling my HPET would fix the issue on my machine, I want to make my program reliable across all machines. Those which have my issue and those which do not. I found that over many many iterations, DateTime.subtract() shows a time period which is 1.28 times more than Stopwatch.elapsed(). DateTime.subtract() is the real ET. On a coworkers PC it is steady around 1.00. I am going to perform several ratio measurements at startup and use the result as a scaler for my StopWatch.elapsed() I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this out, in case anyone else is having a similar issue, I found the solution to my problem. About a month ago, my Windows 7 'Aero' effects began to move VERY slowly. In searching for a solution to that problem, I found the following:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/57307-63-slow-motion-aero-transitions

The solution I used, which is in the link above, is to:

Run CMD as administrator. Type "bcdedit /set useplatformclock true" and press enter (w/o quotation marks). Restarted computer and my problems were resolved.

I don't fully understand the inner-workings of that command, so if someone would like to elaborate, please do. But I know that not only did it solve my slow aero effects, but my stopwatch timer is on the nose now!

Thanks for all your efforts guys, I do appreciate it!

Gary

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting out a guess answer based on the experiments done so far.

The `Stopwatch` class uses the [Windows "performance counter"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx). I have often read that on some systems it returns inaccurate data. This appears to happen with older hardware and/or older operating system versions.

For example, the time can jump around based on what core you are executing on. This probably is not the issue here because your timings are consistently off. But it's an example of problems with this kind of time data.

I guess that Visual Studio uses `Stopwatch` as well.

This also fits the fact that the problem only happens on your machine. The other machines probably have different time hardware.

Try this:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var startDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

Thread.Sleep(200);

sw.Stop();
var endDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

And post the results. My prediction is that the `Stopwatch` version is wrong and the `DateTime`-based version shows a little over 200ms.

As far as I'm aware the Windows Kernel uses the time source that `DateTime.UtcNow` uses for it's own timers and delays. AFAIK that is a hardware interrupt that, by default, ticks at 60Hz and causes the timer to update a global time variable at that rate. This means that even if `DateTime.UtcNow` is wrong it should be consistent with `Thread.Sleep`. But we know that `DateTime.UtcNow` is right. Otherwise you would have noticed significant system time drift.

Maybe you can try disabling the piece of hardware that provides Windows with the high frequency counter. `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution` should return true now and should become false when you disable this piece of hardware. On my machine it's called "HPET" in the device manager.

Comment: In my last edit (#3) I showed exactly that... My DateTime.Now() is incrementing by the desired 200ms, or a little more, while my etWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds is showing around 130-140ms.

Comment: Maybe related to the note [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx): `On a multiprocessor computer, it does not matter which processor the thread runs on. However, because of bugs in the BIOS or the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL), you can get different timing results on different processors. To specify processor affinity for a thread, use the ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity method.`

Comment: @GaryWillette right, that seems to confirm the theory. Try disabling the hardware to obtain proof and mitigation.

Comment: @usr Sorry I don't know how to disable that?? It's not listed in the Device Manager tab of Computer Management... I am showing hidden devices and can't find HPET. Stopwatch.IsHighResolution does indeed return true.

Comment: I have no idea, I'd try the first page of https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=windows+disable+hpet, e.g. http://www.ghacks.net/2013/04/18/try-changing-hpet-settings-to-improve-your-pcs-performance/. If none of that works I think you are at a dead end... If you read through this (https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=windows+hpet+skew) you see that the HPET thing can cause various issues. I never had any of that.

Comment: @usr I disabled it (High Performance Event Timer) in devmgr, but Stopwatch.IsHighResolution is still true when I run my code. Do i need a reboot? It's showing disabled in the devmgr...

Comment: I'd at least reboot Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that apps do not expect their time source to change under them. Reboot.

Comment: Rebooted, still shows 'true' for HighPerformance... Perhaps it needs to be disabled in the BIOS. Haven't tried that. I might follow the path of seeing if my processor is slowing down when it doesn't have much to do, so therefore the number of ticks is less, and the ET is wrong... Posted by @devuxer above. Thoughts?

Comment: This could be true. Run Prime95 in stress mode, wait 10sec, then repeat the test. Did you exhaust all tutorials to disable the timer yet? There might be multiple ways.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the problem. I just need you to confirm the kill :)

Comment: @usr Used Prime95. CPU pegged at 100%.... Same results :'-( This is really, really bugging me now! I thought we had it...

Comment: As long as IsHighResolution returns true I don't think the source of the bad data is shut down yet. You need to hunt the hardware down! :) What did you try to shut it off? BIOS?

Comment: @usr I just did it in the device manager from Windows (7)... I suppose I can try to look for it in the BIOS.

Comment: I don't understand why you are not using all options available given how close you are to the solution. a) devmgr, b) BIOS, c) http://www.ghacks.net/2013/04/18/try-changing-hpet-settings-to-improve-your-pcs-performance/. Try *all*.