# Python strptime missing some milliseconds when running script in different computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am formatting pandas dataframe timestamp column to unix timestamp as follows

```
from datetime import datetime

df["col_in_unix"] = df["example_col"].\
                        apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').timestamp())
```

And when running this on my computer I get from a timestamp

```
datetime.strptime("2020-12-09 13:27:48.172793", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').timestamp()

1607513268.172793
```

but when I run the code in different windows pc I sometimes get answer

```
1607513268.17
```

And this happens to all timestamps in the dataframe column, what gives? I have also made .exe file from the script with Pyinstaller and still the same problem

Comment: What are the 2nd OS that you are running it on?

Comment: it's all on windows 10 with 1809 update @sophros

Comment: To make sure this is not a formatting issue, pease set decimal places to print explicitly, e.g. `print( f"{v:.6f}" )` with v being your value.

Comment: After I printed the value as @MrFuppes suggested, I noticed that the source of the timestamps sometimes had dropped resolution in milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering if this is not related to either:

1. [Differences in system time resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/970031/what-is-meant-by-timer-resolution-in-microseconds) due to different hardware / drivers, etc.
2. [precision setting for `pandas` and/or the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735541/customized-float-formatting-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
3. [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833255/datetime-granularity-between-32bit-and-64bit-windows) described for Windows 32b vs. 64b in C#
   (you are likely to observe a similar problem between 32b and 64b versions of Python).
4. Some other factor

Comment: Thanks for the input, it was unrelated issue to my script. Apparently where I fetch the data had problems and is now fixed :)

Comment: Do you mean different "disk speeds" so that the data reading took different times?