# What is the best way to measure execution time in production (not for performance)?

Tags: c#, time, measure

There are many questions around there asking what is the best way to measure elapsed time for benchmarking and/or testing, but I'm looking for something a bit different.

I would like to measure the elapsed time in a loop, and break it when it reaches a given amount of time. To be clear, see the example below:

```
int elapsedTime = 0;
while (elapsedTime < MAX_TIME) {
    doSomething();
    elapsedTime += time-taken-by-doSomething;
}
```

The doSomething method won't always take the same time (can go from ~3ms to ~50ms) so I really need to measure it each time it gets called.

What would be the best way to get elapsed time in this conditions (ie. not a benchmark, not a test)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Stopwatch class

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
while (stopwatch.Elapsed < MAX_TIME) {
    //Do something
}
```

Be careful if you are doing [multithreaded stuff though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400254/can-the-net-stopwatch-class-be-this-terrible?rq=1)